# Why is electric charge quantized?

Tags: charge, discrete, magnetic-monopoles

Why is electric charge quantized? It is said that charge quantization is a consequence of embedding the abelian gauge group in a simple non-abelian group as is done in theories of Grand Unification. Can somebody explain this in detail (show mathematical steps)? Or is there another explanation?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/97909/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21103/2451 and links therein.

Comment: the fundamental reason is  *because at the particle level only quantized charges have beenobserved*. You are really asking "how is this modeled mathematically"

Comment: Isn't that simply the conserved charge of Dirac field?